# HashSet vs ArrayList CPU usage is high

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, hashset

I am having 104k string values , out of which 89k are unique. I would like to check a string is present in this list or not.

This is my class and its method which hold all these  records.

```
public class TestClass {
    private static TestClass singletonObj = null;
    private List<String> stringList= null;

    public static synchronized TestClass getInstance() {
        if(singletonObj == null) {
            singletonObj = new TestClass();
        }
        return singletonObj;
    }


    public boolean isValidString(String token) {
        if(stringList == null) {
            init();
        }
        if(stringList != null && token != null && !token.isEmpty())
            return stringList.contains(token.toLowerCase());
        return false;
    }

    private init() {
     stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
     // put all 104k values in this data structure.
    }
}
```

My application tries to use this `isValidString()` method concurrently with around 20 requests per second. This works fine but when i tried to change the Data structure to `HashSet`, the CPU usage goes very high. As per my understanding Hashset should perform better[o(1)] than ArrayList[o(n)]. Can anyone explain me why is this happening ?

Comment: Shouldn't your `init()` method be in synchronized block?

Comment: @Codebender Why do we want to do that ? It's called only one time.

Comment: Agree with @Codebender If your call is singleton then you can create it at the time of getInstance(), I believe it will always have only one list or set.

Comment: @Sthita - Your `isValidString()` should have a synchronized block which ensures `init();` is called only once. Also you need to check for `null` twice.

Comment: @Sthita, but your `isValidString()` is called from multiple threads, which means it could go into `init()` multiple times. You should have ideally called `init()` from your `getInstance()` class.

Comment: @Sthita - For a `HashSet` if worst case insertion would be `O(n)` I think this is also slowing down your program (apart from lack of synchronized access to `init()`)

Comment: @Codebender When 1st time isValidString() called then my  stringList will be updated with values, i don't think init() will be called multiple times.

Comment: @Sthita if you invoke this method from multiple thread at same time then you will see that init will be invoke multiple times, not only once as you expect. Even making init will not solve the problem. Make your isValidString synchronized or my suggestion do this list creation in getInstance that is already synchronized

Comment: @ankitkatiyar91, if you make `inValidString()` synchronized it defeats the whole purpose of multithreading, you should only make the `if(stringList==null)` condition synchronized.

Comment: Also do yourself (and the JVM) a favor by specifying the number of elements that your collection is going to hold when instantiating it. This will improve performace

Comment: @TheLostMind Implementing initial capacity seems to be a good idea, but still feel that there wont be any visible improvement for the longer run.

Comment: What's the point of having a lazily instantiated singleton that has a lazily loaded `stringList` anyway? You've got to load the collection before it makes sense to query it, so you're not going to get any parallelism there. So why not initialize in the constructor?

Comment: How does this behave single-threaded?

Comment: My understanding s `HashSet` will first "hash" the input object first in order to compare its fingerprint with the one stored in it since it compares the hashes before, while ArrayList calls just equals directly

Comment: @Sthita - Did you try it?.. It should increase the performance.. use both `synchronized block` and initial capacity. This will certainly increase performance.  Your arraylist elements don't have to be relocated every time the size exceeds the threshold.

Comment: @TheLostMind i have set the initial capacity of arraylist to 250k and have also init() while initializing the class object, but still the question lies what is the problem with HashSet over ArrayList for using contains() ?

Comment: `contains()` for `ArrayList` and `HashSet` is `O(n)` worst case. Given your input size, there will definitely be conflicts (so `HashSet` will not give you `O(1)` performance). You should increase heap size, use G1GC or CMS GC, enable *escape analysis*, use *synchronization* in appropriate place (se my previous comments). :)

Comment: Try with `-verbose:gc`, set very high heap memory limits for start and max (`-Xms8g -Xmx8g`). Add log output in `init()` when adding strings to your `HashSet`.

Comment: @steffen my -Xms and -Xmx was already set to 6G and 8G respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that `HashSet`, being a hash-based structure, computes the hashCode of every String *since the very instant of inserting it* into the HashSet, i.e. in the method `init`. This may be the period along which the CPU goes high, and it's part of the price we pay for getting a better throughput when iterating the values of the structure.

If I'm right, after the method `init` ends, the CPU should drop off, and the speed of the program should increase hugely, and that's the benefit of using HashSet.

By the way: A sure way of optimization is *pre-sizing* the structure:

- ArrayList should have an initial size equal to the maximum number of elements that will contain.
- And HashSet an initial size 1.7 greater than the maximum.

BTW: The standard hash algorithm of `String.hash` computes all of the characters of the string. Maybe you could be content with computing just the first 100 characters, for example (depending on the nature of the data you are processing, of corse). Then, you could encapsulate your Strings into your own class, overriding the `hashCode` method with your own hashing algorithm, and overriding the `equals` method to perform a strict comparation.

Comment: No the CPU usage was not dropping at all and after some time the application stops responding if i am using HashSet. I am using ArrayList and given the initial size.

Comment: And are you using HashSet with an initial size? If not, that could be the cause: A small hash structure that gets overfull, turns unefficient because it becomes a set of long lists.

Comment: @Sthita - Check if GC is kicking in as well

Comment: @LittleSanti Setting HashSet with initial size looks good and working out for me i think. I will keep monitoring my application today and see the impact. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple class to spawn 20 threads that access your dictionary checker every second as per the bottom of this post.

I cannot replicate your results - but this might be because of the input data that I have access to.  I have used your `TestClass` implementation importing ~130,000 words from the English Open Word List ([EOWL](http://dreamsteep.com/downloads/word-games-and-wordsmith-utilities/120-the-english-open-word-list-eowl.html)).    No ongoing high CPU use is seen with either `ArrayList` or `HashSet` as the type of `stringList`.

My guess is that your problem is due to your input data.  I tried adding my input dictionary twice to create duplication - obviously with the `ArrayList` this just makes the list twice as long, but with the `HashSet`, it means the code is throwing out duplicates.  You note that about 1/5 of your input data is duplicate.  With 1/2 duplicates in my tests, I do see a ***slight*** increased CPU for about 2 seconds and then it drops back to almost nothing once `stringList` is initialised.

This "blip" could be more prolonged if your input strings are more complex than the single words I'm using.  So maybe that is your problem.  Alternatively - maybe you have some other code that wraps this part that is hogging CPU.

***N.B.*** I would caution you as others have in comments about your implementation of `init`.  In my experiments, I saw that many threads could call the dictionary check before the dictionary had fully initialised, giving inconsistent results for the same test word.  Why not call it from your constructor, if it is to be a singleton object?

#### Code listings

Your TestClass with some input data code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestClass {
    private static TestClass singletonObj = null;
    //private List<String> stringList = null;

    private HashSet<String> stringList = null;

    public static synchronized TestClass getInstance() {
        if (singletonObj == null) {
            singletonObj = new TestClass();
        }
        return singletonObj;
    }

    public boolean isValidString(String token) {
        if (stringList == null) {
            init();
        }
        if (stringList != null && token != null && !token.isEmpty())
            return stringList.contains(token.toLowerCase());
        return false;
    }

    private void init() {
        String dictDir = "C:\\Users\\Richard\\Documents\\EOWL_CSVs";
        File[] csvs = (new File(dictDir)).listFiles();
        stringList = new HashSet<String>();
        Scanner inFile = null;

        for (File f : csvs) {
            try {
                inFile = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.exit(1);
            }

            while (inFile.hasNext()) {
                stringList.add(inFile.next().toLowerCase()
                        .replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z ]", ""));
            }
            inFile.close();
        }

        System.out.println("Dictionary initialised with " + stringList.size()
                + " members");
    }
}
```

Thread to access it:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

public class DictChecker extends Thread {

    TestClass t = null;
    public static int classId = 0;
    String className = null;
    
    
    public void doWork()
    {
        String testString = "Baby";
        if (t.isValidString(testString))
        {
            System.out.println("Got a valid string " + testString + " in class " + className);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(testString + " not in the dictionary");
        }
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try {
                DictChecker.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            doWork();
        }
    }
    
    public DictChecker()
    {
        t = TestClass.getInstance();
        className = "dChecker" + classId;
        classId += 1;
        System.out.println("Initialised " + className + " in thread " + this.getName());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
             (new DictChecker()).start();
             try {
                DictChecker.sleep(50);//simply to distribute load over the second
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @J Richard Snape yes, i am initializing it from constructor and it is currently HashSet with initial size, Looks good till now.

Comment: @sthita glad you have got it working the way you want :)

Answer (score 0):

JDK `HashSet` is built on top of a `HashMap<T, Object>`, where value is a singleton ‘present’ object. It means that the memory consumption of a HashSet is identical to HashMap: in order to store SIZE values, you need `32 * SIZE + 4 * CAPACITY` bytes (plus size of your values).

For `ArrayList`, it's the capacity of the java.util.ArrayList multiplied by the reference size `(4 bytes on 32bit, 8bytes on 64bit) + [Object header + one int and one references]`.

*So **HashSet** is definitely not a memory-friendly collection.*

Depends if you're using a `32-bit` or a `64-bit` VM. That said, HashSet gets hurt worse by `8-byte` references than ArrayList does -- adding an extra `4 bytes` per reference, based on the linked memory consumption chart, brings ArrayList up to `~12` bytes per element, and HashSet up to `~52` bytes per element.)

ArrayList is implemented using an array of Objects. Figure below shows the memory usage and layout of an ArrayList on a 32-bit Java runtime:

**Memory usage and layout of a ArrayList on a 32-bit Java runtime**
[image]

The figure above shows that when an `ArrayList` is created, the result is an `ArrayList` object using `32 bytes` of memory, along with an Object array at a default size of `10`, totaling `88 bytes` of memory for an empty `ArrayList`. This means that the `ArrayList` is not accurately sized and therefore has a default capacity, which happens to be `10 entries`.

### Attributes of an ArrayList

`Default capacity` -    *10*

`Empty size`      -    *88 bytes*

`Overhead`  -    *48 bytes plus 4 bytes per entry*

`Overhead` for 10K collection   - *~40K*

`Search/insert/delete performance`- *O(n) — Time taken is linearly dependent to the number of elements*

A HashSet has fewer capabilities than a HashMap in that it cannot contain more than one null entry and cannot have duplicate entries. The implementation is a wrapper around a HashMap, with the HashSet object managing what is allowed to be put into the HashMap object. The additional function of restricting the capabilities of a HashMap means that HashSets have a slightly higher memory overhead.

**Memory usage and layout of a HashSet on a 32-bit Java runtime**
[image]

The figure above shows the shallow heap (memory usage of the individual object) in bytes, along with the retained heap (memory usage of the individual object and its child objects) in bytes for a java.util.HashSet object. The shallow heap size is `16 bytes`, and the retained heap size is `144 bytes`. When a HashSet is created, its default capacity — the number of entries that can be put into the set — is `16 entries`. When a HashSet is created at the default capacity and no entries are put into the set, it occupies `144 bytes`. This is an extra `16 bytes` over the memory usage of a HashMap.

Table below shows the attributes of a HashSet:

### Attributes of a HashSet

`Default capacity`  -*16 entries*

`Empty size`    -*144 bytes*

`Overhead`  -*16 bytes plus HashMap overhead*

`Overhead for a 10K collection` -*16 bytes plus HashMap overhead*

`Search/insert/delete performance`  - O(1) — 
*Time taken is constant time, regardless of the number of elements 
(assuming no hash collisions)*

Comment: The reference shows the performance is better for iteration, here we just want to compare/ check for availability of the token in the list/set.

Comment: "If you don't care about ... the performance of contains" but `contains` *is* the method we're calling most often here, right?

Comment: @Sthita - See the capacity in reference 2 and the added capacity for arrayList above.

Comment: OP is talking about CPU usage, not memory. They obviously *do* care about performance of contains.